# Moving a Home Page Same Site Collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, modern-experience, 2019, modern-pages

I have a migrated site (from SharePoint 2016 to SharePoint 2019).  My migrated site doesn't have some of the same features and same look that are found on modern site in SharePoint 2019.  I want to get the migrated modern page site features and look for my migrated site home page. How can I do this? These are some methods I was thinking but don't know if this is smart way

- create a new page using the modern experience
- create a new page in a new subsite in the same site collection and save as template and make it my new home page

Probably not right on any points. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

The classic pages/sites will remain classic after migration. The best practice would be to build everything from scratch in modern experience.

Also quoting from this document: [Differences between modern and classic experiences for lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/differences-between-sharepoint-server-2016-and-2019-ba84c8a3-3ce2-4252-926e-c67654ceb4a3):

> There's not a 1:1 mapping between all features on a classic site and a
> modern team site. But site collection administrators can update the
> home page to the new home page experience. To do so, create a modern
> page with the web parts you want and then set it as the home page for
> your classic site.

Comment: Thanks. What if Page is missing from +new drop down?

Comment: @SharePointLady Possibly because the Site Page feature is not enabled. Go to Site settings > Manage site features and activate the "Site Pages" feature. After that, add the Site Page content type to the Page Library.

Answer (score 0):

There is no conversion process from classic to modern. For pages, you need to recreate pages as modern from scratch. If you want the site to use a modern template (Communications or Teams), then you need to create a new site.